# required rep for editing questions and answers

Tags: support

I just approved a suggested edit by someone with over 5700 rep. According to [this page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit) you only need 2000 rep to edit. So why was approval needed here?

Comment: Was it actually a Question/Answer? I just saw a bunch come in as tag  wiki edits that came in by someone with 5,748 rep...

Comment: @Kellenjb - you're right, it was a wiki edit. But, while I can't find the required rep to edit a tag wiki, accepting a suggested edit only takes 5000 rep, and I would assume that editing would need less. Right?

Comment: @stevenvh, editing a tag wiki directly requires that you have gained certain prestige in that tag. I will find a source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tag wikis have much higher requirements to edit than other posts, to edit tag wikis *without* going through the suggestion stage you need the [Trusted User](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) privilege (requiring 20000 rep).
>
> Otherwise, all edits move to the suggestion queue, where a few users with the [Approve Tag Wiki Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) privilege can work together to edit a wiki.

[From DMA57361 here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94448/152553).

This is because when you edit a single post it bumps to the front page and receives review, on tag wikis once they are approved they do not see review unless someone stumbles upon it. Instead we have a review process built in unless you hit 20k rep.